# I want to know about what to put in () to change int to floats in value

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am working with regular expressions moving numbers in a file to a list then adding all the numbers up. I am having problems understanding what I need to put into the value parentheses to get those numbers to be a float.

```
import re
fhand = open('regex_sum_42.txt')
numlist = list()
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    value = re.findall('([0-9.]+)', line)
    num = float(value())  # Need to know what to put in the value () .
    numlist.append(num)
print value
```

Comment: 1. If findall returns a list, that won't be directly castable to a float. Do you want to cast the list's contents instead? 2. If `value` isn't a list, you probably shouldn't be calling it. Just remove the parentheses.

Comment: `re.findall` will always return  a list. By the way if your input is untrusted, which I think is because you read from a file, this regexp pattern will find patterns like `1234.1234.1234` as well. Anyways you should put something like `map(float, value)` instead of `value()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here Two problems are present ...

1: To convert values in to float you have to iterate over it convert it into float or simply map it on value list.

2: your regex for float and int number are not perfect ...

```
import re
fhand = open('regex_sum_42.txt')
numlist = list()
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    value = re.findall(r'[+-]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?', line)
    num = [float(i[0]) for i in value] # this is simply fetch first element from list of tuples and convert in into float                        
print value
```